# Lower border not visible

Tags: java, swing, border

I have two versions of code and don't understand why they don't look the same:

**Version 1:**

```
urlButton = new JButton("URL");
borderLayout.add(urlButton, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

**Version 2:**

```
JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
rightPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(0, 0, 0));
urlButton = new JButton("URL");
rightPanel.add(urlButton);
borderLayout.add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

In Version 2 the urlButton's lower border can't be seen. How can I fix this? I need Version 2 because I want to add more elements to the `rightPanel`.

**EDIT:** I don't think that the border is really missing. It is just not visible anymore. I guess that using the `FlowLayout` there is some extra padding or margin which moves my `JButton` a pixel lower such that the border is overpainted by another component. But I don't know where to look for such extra padding/margin to set it to 0.

**EDIT 2:** I created a MCVE and see the problem now.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MCVE extends JFrame {

    private MCVE(boolean missingBorder) {
        super(String.format("MCVE (missingBorder: %b)", missingBorder));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JButton("MIDDLE"));
        add(new JButton("LOWER"), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(0, 0, 0));

        JButton urlButton = new JButton("URL");

        if (missingBorder) {
            rightPanel.add(urlButton);
            add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        } else {
            add(urlButton, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        }

        setSize(500, 88);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MCVE(true);
        new MCVE(false);
    }

}
```

I unconsciously expected the `FlowLayout` to adjust the height of the `JButton`. But of course the `FlowLayout` presents the `JButton` in its preferred size. In my case the preferred height is bigger than there is space so I don't see the lower border of the button.

Do you have any recommendation which Layout to choose? I want the preferred width of the Button but the height of the parent component.

Comment: missing there any borders, hmmm [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) hasn't something with LineBorder[Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)

Comment: @mKorbel I hope my edit makes it clearer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to increase the size of your panel?

Comment: Could you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that has the problem?

Comment: @JavaDoe I added a MCVE and that showed me the problem. Thanks. MCVE really help sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you want (I guess) you should use `GridLayout`. Exchange the line

```
rightPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(0, 0, 0));
```

with

```
rightPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
```

that should do the trick. You also can add as many buttons as you want to that panel and they will always scale to fit the panel.

**EDIT**

To place the content next to each other you can use `GridBagLayout` with an adapted `GridBagConstraint`. The following code does that for you:

```
rightPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();
constraint.weighty = 1.0;
constraint.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
```

and to add your components

```
rightPanel.add(urlButton, constraint);
rightPanel.add(checkbox, constraint);
```

If you don't want to use the complicated `GridBagConstraints` you can improvise using `BorderLayout` for up to 3 components next to each other. You can then add your button and checkbox using:

```
rightPanel.add(urlButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
rightPanel.add(checkbox, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Comment: What I finally want (why I introduce the `JPanel`) is to add a checkbox next to the url button. But the checkbox needs less space. So I can't use a `GridLayout` because it gives each component the same space. I want both components to get the width they prefer and the height of the parent component.

Comment: With `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS` the button and the checkbox are on top of each other but I want them next to each other. If I take `BoxLayout.X_AXIS` instead they are next to each other but with the preferred height. I want the height of the parent component.

Comment: Is it enough to only have two fields? Or should it be dynamic if you want to add more content?

Comment: I adapted the answer to place them next to each other and having the height of the parent and their preferred width...

Comment: If it works it would be great if you could mark the answer as accepted to indicate the problem is solved. Otherwise feel free to state the problem with this solution...